# Ajax.BeginForm refresh partial..?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Okay so, I have a form that is posting using ajax...

```
<% using(Ajax.BeginForm(new AjaxOptions() { OnBegin="onBegin", OnSuccess = "onSuccess", OnFailure="onFailure"  })) { %>
```

On the server side I am passing back from the controller a Json object. Now, when the OnSuccess event fires I can get to the Json object by using "result.get_response().get_object()"...

My question is, I need to be able to refresh a partial on the page with a list of items that are in the Json object...

Thoughts on how I can do this..?

Answer (score 1):

Use jQuery, and spin through the returned JSON object, building whatever you like.

Example:

```
  $.each(json, function(i, item) {
        //Add a dinner to the list on the right
        $('#dinnerList').append($('<li/>')
                              .attr("class", "dinnerItem")
                              .append($('<a/>').attr("href", "/Dinners/Details/" + item.ID)
                              .html(item.Name)).append("SomeThing"));
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that you will find the below code helpful.

Firstly, create an AJAX form with

- RefreshAjaxList: the name ajax action of current controller
- string.empty (optional)
- AJAX option
- id of form (optional)
- when click status, we will edit the status call server to update the status
- after edit the status, we call submit button to call `RefreshAjaxList`; the button is `display:none`
- in this example, I have one controller: `AjaxController` with 2 actions:

```
public ActionResult UpdateStatus(int contactId, Status contactStatus)
{  
    ContactRepository repo = new ContactRepository();
    repo.UpdateStatus(contactId, contactStatus);
    return Json("success:true");
}

[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
[ActionName("RefreshAjaxList")]
public ActionResult RefreshContact()
{
    ContactRepository repo = new ContactRepository();
    IList<Contact> list = repo.List();
    return PartialView("AjaxUc/AjaxList", repo.List());
}
```

JavaScript:

```
var status = { active: 1, inactive: 0 };
function editStatus(cell, id, active) {
    if (active)
        cell.innerHTML = "<input type='radio' checked='true' name='active" + id + "' onclick='updateStatus(this, " + id + ", true);'>Active</input>" +
                             "<input type='radio' name='active" + id + "' onclick='updateStatus(this, " + id + ", false);'>Inactive</input>";
    else
        cell.innerHTML = "<input type='radio' name='active" + id + "' onclick='updateStatus(this, " + id + ", true);'>Active</input>" +
                             "<input type='radio' checked='false' name='active" + id + "' onclick='updateStatus(this, " + id + ", false);'>Inactive</input>";
}
    

function updateStatus(radio, id, active) {
    if (radio.checked != active) {
        if (confirm("Do you want to change the status of the contract?")) {
            if (active)
                cStatus = status.active;
            else
                cStatus = status.inactive;
            $.ajax({
                url: 'Ajax/UpdateStatus',
                dataType: "json",
                data: { contactId: id, contactStatus: cStatus },
                success: function(html) {
                    jQuery("#divAjaxList").submit();
                },
                error: function(request, desc, ex) {
                    alert(desc);
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Your ASP script:

```
<% using (Ajax.BeginForm("RefreshAjaxList", "abc", new AjaxOptions() { UpdateTargetId = "divContent" }, new { @id = "divAjaxList" }))
   {%>
<div id="divContent">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>
            </th>
            <th>
                Id
            </th>
            <th>
                FirstName
            </th>
            <th>
                LastName
            </th>
            <th>
                Phone
            </th>
            <th>
                Email
            </th>
            <th>
                Status
            </th>
        </tr>
        <% foreach (var item in Model)
           { %>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <%= Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.Id })%>
                |
                <%= Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ })%>
            </td>
            <td>
                <%= Html.Encode(item.Id)%>
            </td>
            <td>
                <%= Html.Encode(item.FirstName)%>
            </td>
            <td>
                <%= Html.Encode(item.LastName)%>
            </td>
            <td>
                <%= Html.Encode(item.Phone)%>
            </td>
            <td>
                <%= Html.Encode(item.Email)%>
            </td>
            <td ondblclick="editStatus(this,<%=item.Id %>, <%= item.Status.GetHashCode() %>);">
                <%= item.Status== Status.Active ? "Active" :"Inactive" %>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <% } %>
    </table>
    <input type="submit" id="refresh" style="display:none" />
</div>
<% } %>
```

For more info, mail to pnguyen2@firstlook.com for further discussion.

Hope this can help u.

Answer (score 0):

create the user control for the list of items to be displayed and render it as partial by passing the json data to the UC. This will refresh partially

Comment: can you give me an example. I'm unsure of how to pass the json data to the UC after the form is submitted...

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [JTemplate](http://jtemplates.tpython.com/) to render JSON data